# progress through powerpoint with macros not working on second slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a macro which will run through slides in a powerpoint presentation. I had it working, but now it has stopped working and I don't know why.

The vbscript to run through the slides and animation are

```
Private Sub PPTEvent_SlideShowNextBuild(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    Sleep 1000
    SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
End Sub


Private Sub PPTEvent_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    Sleep 1000   
    SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
End Sub
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I can't see where the problem is, I've tried removing Sleep 1000 as well, but no dice.

Strangely, if I use both

```
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
```

together, it runs through the entire slideshow as I'd hoped.

Comment: enable events are off maybe ?, just an idea... .

Comment: @Jaun Ruiz de Castilla, I don't think so as I'm getting most events, just not all, and I can progress through by using both ENTER and RIGHT

Comment: Actually @JuanRuizdeCastilla there is no such property on the Application object in PPT. The events are enabled if the custom class object PPTEvent is active. Knowing how that is declared and instantiated is an important piece of information that is missing here.

Comment: @CoolBlue I didn't realize the PPTEvent initialization was important. I do know that is how I'm listening for the nextSlide and nextBuild. I'm not sure I understand what the missing bit of information is. If you let me know, I can update the question later today when I have the code in front of me.

Comment: If your running this code in PowerPoint then there is no standard object called PPTEvents so you must be declaring that as an application object inside a class module and it won't do anything unless you instantiated the class and that can only be done through user intersection or using one of the OnSlideshowXXX Events, with a handler properly declared in a standard module. There are a lot of things that have to be done properly before you can run the above code so I suggest it would be useful to include that background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way based on the help for [SlideShowSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff746375(v=office.15).aspx)

There is an error in the MSDN page which I have corrected below (need to use msoTrue/False not True/False for LoopUntilStopped).

It starts automatically when you enter SlideShow mode and the animations run OK.

In a standard Module...

```
Public showRunning As Boolean

Sub runSlides()

  showRunning = True
  For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides
    With s.SlideShowTransition
      .AdvanceOnTime = msoTrue
      .AdvanceTime = 1
    End With
  Next

  With ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings

    .RangeType = ppShowAll
    .AdvanceMode = ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings
    .LoopUntilStopped = msoFalse
    .ShowWithAnimation = msoTrue
    .Run

  End With

End Sub

Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)

  If Not showRunning Then
    runSlides
  End If

End Sub

Public Sub OnSlideShowTerminate(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
  showRunning = False
  closeSlideShow
End Sub

Public Sub closeSlideShow()
Dim s As Slide

  For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides
    With s.SlideShowTransition
      .AdvanceOnTime = msoFalse
    End With
  Next

  On Error Resume Next
  ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit
  On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

EDIT:

Added the closeSlideShow routine to stop slideshow running every time.

Note: setting .AdvanceOnTime to msoFalse programatically or manually un-checking Use Timings in the SLIDE SHOW ribbon tab, will stop the slideshow from running.  It seems that setting this to msoTrue, having entered with it set to msoFalse, and trying to do ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run in the same routine will not work!

Comment: Very nice @CoolBlue, thank you. I was just coming in to share the way I accessed the `PPTEvent`, and it was like this Set cPPTObject.PPTEvent = Application`. I'll give your new code here a go. Looks nice.

Comment: Very nice @CoolBlue, one issue I seem to be having is that powerpoint crashes on the closeSlideShow function. I've set loop to True, and if the slideIndex is 1, I know it's looped, and that the slideshow should exit. Seems like anything related to View.Exit is crashing ppt. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In general, SendKeys should be avoided. Why don't you try something like

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub GoThroughSlides()
    Dim sl As PowerPoint.Slide
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run
    For Each sl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Sleep 3000 '
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Activate
        SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide sl.SlideNumber
    Next sl
End Sub
```

Comment: Though I agree that the SendKeys should be avoided, I'm trying to get both the Slides and the animations within each slide. Is there a way to trigger the `SlideShowWindows(1).View.MainSequence.Timeline` or something like that to get each slide to run through it's animation sequence?

Comment: Hmm I did some research around but it appears Powerpoint VBA object model does not support triggering animations. Although i have a good grasp of Excel and its object model, not nearly as good with PowerPoint. My suggestion/question, isn't possible to set up animations in PowerPoint as soon as a slide is open. If you can do this than the code I have provided should work. Please let me know. This is a good question. I am up voting it.

Comment: Thanks Jeanno, I'll accept your answer for this question and open a new question regarding triggering animations. Though I can set each animation to run automatically, I'm trying to run this as an add-in not a macro, and don't really want to change the animation settings in the presentation.