# Send Keys is Disabling NumLock

Tags: vba, excel, sendkeys, num-lock

### Issue:

Upon me using `SendKeys` to copy data from an Excel application to another (non-Microsoft) application, my Num Lock becomes disabled.

```
Sub Test()

    Range("A1:B71").Select
    SendKeys "^C" 'Copies Selected Text

    AppActivate "AccuTerm 2K2"
    SendKeys "2", True    'Enters to notes screen
    SendKeys "^M", True   'Confirms above (Enter key)
    SendKeys "^V", True   'Pastes into client application

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    'Providing time for client application to finish
    'pasting...

    SendKeys "^M", True   'Next three enters are to
    SendKeys "^M", True   '...exit notes section
    SendKeys "^M", True
    AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

    Range("B52:B62").Clear  'Clears the Template
    Range("B52").Select     'Resets Cell Position

End Sub
```

### Preferred Resolution:

What can be done to prevent my code from disabling the NumLock - or how can I go about re-enabling numlock once my code completes?

Comment: You can try looking into `shell` to see if you can open your program that way. Regarding numlock, I have a class module I use which I will post below shortly.

Comment: just a thought - what if you break this line: `Application.SendKeys "2^M^V"` into 3 lines? the do the same with `"~~~%{TAB}"`

Comment: Break up your send keys. Don't put two on the same line (ALT-TAB excepted).  Also, I use sendkeys too sometimes, and it turns on/off NumLock/CapsLock for me too. I think that's just part of SendKeys.  Also, try adding `, True` after sendkeys, i.e. `Application.Sendkeys "~", True`.  Also, what if you do `Dim myTxt as String // myTxt = "%{TAB}" // ...Sendkeys myTxt, True`

Comment: @findwindow The program is already open when I want to run the script. I don't use shell very often so I am not sure of a way to switch between windows. I am about to implement your NumLockClass though - thanks for that!

Comment: I don't use `shell` ever so I don't know how it works. Just found it after googling for 2 seconds. My idea was to open it with code that way you can set it to an object and forgo `sendkeys`.

Comment: First of all, sendkeys should be the last alternative when the program doesn't have a native way to call (for example java instances), are you sure the program can't be referenced in Excel VBA? [Check this topic for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247552/progress-through-powerpoint-with-macros-not-working-on-second-slide), why to use sendkeys to powerpoint when you can add the reference to it and call easlier the function that you want to?

Comment: I am using AccuTerm that emulates a very very old VT terminal. There is most certainly no Java associated with this terminal.

Comment: You can try making AccuTerm 2K2 VBA script instead http://www.zumasys.com/atfiles/manuals/at2k2/AccuTerm-2K2-Programmers-Guide.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this to turn numlock back on. I forget where I found this on the internet. I did not author it.

> NumLockClass

Place this in a class module.

```
Option Explicit

' API declarations
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetVersionEx Lib "Kernel32" _
        Alias "GetVersionExA" _
        (lpVersionInformation As OSVERSIONINFO) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal bVk As Byte, _
        ByVal bScan As Byte, _
        ByVal dwflags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyboardState Lib "user32" _
        (pbKeyState As Byte) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetKeyboardState Lib "user32" _
        (lppbKeyState As Byte) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetVersionEx Lib "Kernel32" _
        Alias "GetVersionExA" _
        (lpVersionInformation As OSVERSIONINFO) As Long

    Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal bVk As Byte, _
        ByVal bScan As Byte, _
        ByVal dwflags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

    Private Declare Function GetKeyboardState Lib "user32" _
        (pbKeyState As Byte) As Long

    Private Declare Function SetKeyboardState Lib "user32" _
        (lppbKeyState As Byte) As Long
#End If

' Type declaration
Private Type OSVERSIONINFO
    dwOSVersionInfoSize As Long
    dwMajorVersion As Long
    dwMinorVersion As Long
    dwBuildNumber As Long
    dwPlatformId As Long
    szCSDVersion As String * 128
End Type


'Constant declarations
Const VK_NUMLOCK = &H90
Const VK_SCROLL = &H91
Const VK_CAPITAL = &H14
Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = &H1
Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2

Property Get value() As Boolean
'   Get the current state
    Dim keys(0 To 255) As Byte
    GetKeyboardState keys(0)
    value = keys(VK_NUMLOCK)
End Property

Property Let value(boolVal As Boolean)
    Dim o As OSVERSIONINFO
    Dim keys(0 To 255) As Byte
    o.dwOSVersionInfoSize = Len(o)
    GetVersionEx o
    GetKeyboardState keys(0)
'   Is it already in that state?
    If boolVal = True And keys(VK_NUMLOCK) = 1 Then Exit Property
    If boolVal = False And keys(VK_NUMLOCK) = 0 Then Exit Property
'   Toggle it
    'Simulate Key Press
    keybd_event VK_NUMLOCK, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0
    'Simulate Key Release
    keybd_event VK_NUMLOCK, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or _
      KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
End Property

Sub Toggle()
'   Toggles the state
    Dim o As OSVERSIONINFO
    o.dwOSVersionInfoSize = Len(o)
    GetVersionEx o
    Dim keys(0 To 255) As Byte
    GetKeyboardState keys(0)
    'Simulate Key Press
    keybd_event VK_NUMLOCK, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0
    'Simulate Key Release
    keybd_event VK_NUMLOCK, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or _
      KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
End Sub
```

Use it like:

```
Dim numLock As New NumLockClass
If numLock.value = False Then numLock.value = True  'turn it back on
```

Comment: Holy cow - this is great. As I mentioned above, I think using `SendKeys` results in the toggling of the keys, as I can't figure out why it does so.  I'll have to incorporate this into my codes. Cheers :D

Comment: People keep bringing him up when talking to me, and I'm not sure why..... <_<                                                 >_>

Comment: Alfred sold you out =P

Comment: @KDavis did you name it `NumLockClass`?

Comment: I have posted a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69691442/sendkeys-is-messing-with-numlock-when-running-macro-from-vba-editor) about your code, it works usually fine, but if I run VBA `SendKeys "^{END}"` and I use your code afterwards, the property `value` returns True when NumLock is off and False when NumLock is on !!??

Comment: I tried using this code but it has some bugs like the one mentioned by Sandra Rossi. I fixed the code and posted as another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a NumLock module for you to easily check and modify NumLock key situation.

This was based on **findwindow**'s answer, then I fixed some bugs, simplified usage and optimized, so now you have the global Numlock property instead of needing to instance a class object:

***NumLock module:***

```
Option Explicit

' API declarations
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "USER32" ( _
                                ByVal bVk As Byte, _
                                ByVal bScan As Byte, _
                                ByVal dwflags As Long, _
                                ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "USER32" (ByVal nVKey As Long) As Integer
#Else
    Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" ( _
                                ByVal bVk As Byte, _
                                ByVal bScan As Byte, _
                                ByVal dwflags As Long, _
                                ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "USER32" (ByVal nVKey As Long) As Integer
#End If

'Constant declarations
Private Const VK_NUMLOCK = &H90
Private Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = &H1
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2

'===================================================================
'PROPERTIES
'

'=========================================
'Returns the current Numlock state
Public Property Get Numlock() As Boolean
    Numlock = Numlock_State
End Property

'=========================================
'Sets the Numlock state
'   true = turn numlock on
'   false = turn numlock off
Public Property Let Numlock(State As Boolean)
    If State <> Numlock_State Then Numlock_Toggle
End Property

'===================================================================
'METHODS
'

'=========================================
'Returns the current Numlock state
Private Function Numlock_State() As Boolean
    DoEvents    'Required for key messages to be processed
    Numlock_State = CBool(GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK))
End Function

'=========================================
'Sets the Numlock state
'
'   State:  true = turn numlock on
'           false = turn numlock off
Private Sub Numlock_Set(State As Boolean)
    If State <> Numlock_State Then Numlock_Toggle
End Sub

'=========================================
'Toggles the Numlock state
Public Sub Numlock_Toggle()
    Dim previous_state As Boolean
    previous_state = Numlock_State
    
    keybd_event VK_NUMLOCK, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0  'Simulate Numlock key Press
    keybd_event VK_NUMLOCK, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0        'Simulate Numlock key Release
    
End Sub
```

**Usage examples:**

```
Public Sub Example()
    'Turn Numlock on:
    Numlock = True

    'Turn Numlock off:
    Numlock = False
    
    'Check Numlock state:
    Dim IsOn As Boolean
    IsOn = Numlock
    
    'Toggle Numlock state:
    Numlock_Toggle
End Sub
```