# SendKeys is messing with NumLock when running macro from VBA editor

Tags: vba, sendkeys

Sorry to ask again this NumLock/SendKeys question, but I couldn't find a relevant answer in Stack Overflow.

My question is about the VBA class module `NumLockClass` proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018381/9150270).

I created the below normal module in my MS Word Office 365 version.

To reproduce the issue:

- Create the VBA class module `NumLockClass` as proposed in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018381/9150270), and create a normal module with the code below.
- Make sure that your keyboard has the NumLock key light **off** (pressing the <kbd>1</kbd> of the numeric pad is then like pressing the <kbd>End</kbd> key)
- Run the macro `test` of the normal module below, directly from the VBA editor (position the cursor in the macro `test` and press <kbd>F5</kbd>)
- The input popup indicates "NumLock is deactivated", as expected
- Type <kbd>1</kbd> in the input field via the numeric pad, nothing is shown as expected, because pressing <kbd>1</kbd> when the NumLock key is off is like pressing the <kbd>End</kbd> key
- Now type <kbd>a</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to activate programatically the NumLock key
- The input popup indicates "NumLock is activated", and on your keyboard you can see that the NumLock key light is on, as expected
- Type <kbd>1</kbd> in the input field via the numeric pad, and `1` is shown as expected
- Now replace `1` with `e` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which executes programatically `SendKeys "^{END}"` (simulates <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>)

The input popup indicates "NumLock is activated", but on your keyboard you can see the NumLock key light is off and if I type <kbd>1</kbd> via the numeric pad, nothing happens i.e the NumLock has really been deactivated.

As we know, the reason is that `SendKeys "^{END}"` is messing with the NumLock key and it's buggy.

My question is not about why `SendKeys "^{END}"` is messing with the NumLock key, it's **why does the class module given in the other Stack Overflow answer is unable to detect the right status of the NumLock key**, and how to solve?

Thank you.

```
Dim numLock As New NumLockClass

Sub test()
    Do
        If numLock.value = False Then
            k = InputBox("NumLock is deactivated, pressing digit keys in the Numeric Pad does nothing." & vbCrLf & "- Type 'a' to activate NumLock" & vbCrLf & "- Type 'e' to type Ctrl+End")
        Else
            k = InputBox("NumLock is activated, press digit keys in the Numeric Pad to type a number." & vbCrLf & "- Type 'd' to deactivate NumLock" & vbCrLf & "- Type 'e' to type Ctrl+End")
        End If
        If k = "a" Then
            numLock.value = True
        ElseIf k = "d" Then
            numLock.value = False
        ElseIf k = "e" Then
            SendKeys "^{END}"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a known issue that goes back at least a decade.  The simple solution is _Don't use `SendKeys`_ - it's a really bad idea and can mess up other things as well, in ways that are extremely hard to debug.

Comment: The answer you quoted has some bugs that I have fixed. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70883466/4932683) for a fixed version of the Numlock module.